# No audio via HDMI

Tags: audio, hdmi

I have a Dell Inspiron N4010 running Win 7 Ultimate. When I connect the laptop to the TV via HDMI, I get Video but no audio. When the tv is connected, the test sounds are heard from the tv. But when I try to play any media it plays ONLY on the laptop speakers. I have tried updating the audio drivers, reinstalling Realtek Audio, but to no avail. I also do not see HDMI option in the Sounds/ Playback.
Would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'the test sounds are heard from the tv'? How do you play test sounds without the corresponding playback device?

Answer (score 1):

On your pc you may have to go to the bios. When there look for HDMI/HD Audio then click enable.
Exit bios but Save Changes. Allow the pc to boot. Then right click the speaker Icon at the System Tray. Click Playback Devices. The HD/HDMI Icon should be present. Make sure you initiate "Show Disabled/Disconnected Devices". Enable if necessary

Answer (score 0):

HDMI audio output feature handled with graphic card, and its driver, check that you have the latest video driver installed.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the windows audio icon, and open Playback Devices. If supported, your HDMI audio should show up there somewhere..

Select it and set it to default. You may need to relog to Windows for it to work but it should work.